# how do I add bookmark into a pdfpcell

Tags: itext, bookmarks, pdfptable

I am doing a report which contains more 1000 records by using pdfptable of itext. it is not easy to seek a particular record, so i am wondering if there is any way to add bookmark in a pdfpcell.

Answer (score 2):

To add bookmarks into a pdf using iTextSharp, you have to use the Chapter and/or Section objects.  While technically, you can make this work, the Chapter and Section objects have some limitations and some pretty large overhead, especially for 1000's of items.  Also, I have never been able to stop the chapter and section numbers from being displayed in my document, which is probably an issue for you if your content is in pdfpcells.

This [link](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/84/iTextSharp-Links-and-Bookmarks) provides a good introduction to adding Bookmarks to a pdf.  Scroll down to almost the end of the article for the Bookmark section.

Also in this article, is information about setting LocalDestinations in a pdf.  These don't show up as Bookmarks, and they require both a 'Goto' link and a 'Destination'.  So, if you were willing or able to create an index page in your pdf, this might be a better solution.  Your index page would contain all of the 'Goto' links, and the content in your pdfpcells would be the LocalDestinations.